# Computernames in Export-CSV in ForEach-Object

Tags: .net, powershell, csv, foreach

I'm trying to get the installed .NET Framework version of each of the Computers in my `ComputerNames.csv` File.
That's my Code so far:

```
$ComputerNames = Import-csv $ListPath\ComputerNames.csv
$ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -recurse |
Get-ItemProperty -name Version -EA 0 |
# Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} |
Select Version
} | Export-Csv "$ExportPath\FrameWorkVersion-$DateTime.csv"
```

When I run this code, it creates a CSV Output of all the installed .NET Framework Versions, which is nice. But i'd like to have it sortet to the computername.

It's difficult for me to explain this in english so here's an example:

Output so far:

```
TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Version
2.0.50727.4927
2.0.50727.4927
3.0.30729.4926
3.0.30729.4926
3.0.30729.7903
3.0.4506.4926
3.0.6920.4902
3.5.30729.4926
3.5.30729.5003
4.5.51641
4.5.51641
4.5.51641
```

I'd like to have it like this:

```
TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Version
Computer 1
2.0.50727.4927
2.0.50727.4927
3.0.30729.4926
3.0.30729.4926
3.0.30729.7903
Computer 2
3.0.4506.4926
3.0.6920.4902
3.5.30729.4926
3.5.30729.5003
4.5.51641
Computer 3
4.5.51641
4.5.51641
```

Is that possible?

Comment: How did you access different computers? I does not see that in your code.

Comment: I have all computernames in a csv which are loaded in the $ComputerNames Variable. Then I go for a foreach-object. I'm new to powershell and coding in general, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I does not see how you use value of `$ComputerNames` variable. Currently your code execute command on your current PC multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you might be piping your computer names to `ForEach-Object` but you're not using them for anything, so effectively, you're re-running the same query on your own machine a number of times.

You can use `Invoke-Command` to run the script on remote machines, like this:

```
$ComputerNames = Import-csv $ListPath\ComputerNames.csv
$ComputerNames | ForEach-Object {
    # $_ refers to the current item in the pipeline, in this case, an object with a computer name in the "name" property
    $ComputerName = $_.Name
    $ScriptBlock = {
        Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name Version -EA 0 | Select-Object Version
    }
    # This is where the magic happens
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock | Select @{Name="Computer";Expression = { $ComputerName } },Version
} | Export-Csv "$ExportPath\FrameWorkVersion-$DateTime.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Now, thanks to the calculated property `@{Name="Computer";Expression={$ComputerName}}` in the select statement after `Invoke-Command`, you csv will have a "Computer" column *and* a "Version" column

Comment: Thank you for that. I get an multiple errors now on the Invoke-Command line which says "at least one computername is invalid". In the csv I saved the computernames as NetBios Name like this: PCNAME. I also tried it with PCNAME.DOMAIN but i still get the error. any ideas why there's an error?

Comment: @Simipied what is the column name/header of the computer names in you csv file?

Comment: The Import-CSV? First row is: `#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer` Second row: `Name` And then from the third to last row are Computernames. The Export-CSV is empty

Comment: @Simipied My bad, update the script to refer to the `Name` property of each row, instead of the entire row